# how i can check that the url ends with /

Tags: c#

How i can check that the url i have "/" at the end?

when i try this

```
(URL.LastIndexOf('/') != -1)
```

It gives me true even it does not have it. how i can check the whole string has "/" at the end, like `google.com/` have "/" at the end and `google.com` does not have it.

how i can do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
url.EndsWith("/")
```

[String.EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz.aspx)

Comment: You can also do a lot more validation using Regex. A way more stylish way.

Comment: @steven Regex is easy, and its way cooler than writing your own loops :)

Comment: @Drknezz, the author of this comment just wants to know if a string ends in '/', or not.  This answer is precise, and exactly what he needs to know.  RegEx is NOT the solution to this.  It is very powerful and overkill for this kind of thing.  Also there are no loops involved, here.

Comment: @Drknezz, trolls on my SO? No wai!

Comment: @Moo-Juice I just suggested that he should look upon Regex if he needed more validation, instead of manually cranking those loops togerther. @Steven Im on your SO's, trolling your comments XD Anyways, see what i replied to Moo

Comment: @Drknezz, *what* loops?  *what* extra validation?

Comment: @Moo Read my comment again... i said *if he needed more validation*